# Probability of winning a bet when invest half every time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Suppose I have a betting game that wins with a probability of 0.4. If I win the money doubles, else I lose all.

Initially I have 10 dollars, every time I will put half of all my money in the bet, what's the probability that I eventually get 20 dollars and what's the expected times of bets?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to solve with Markov chain but there are two many cases so I don't think it's the right approach. Now I'm stuck on generating ideas tbh.